# How to reuse a relational algebra expression without using assignment operator?

Tags: relational-algebra

Can I write the following expression

(σ<sub>θ</sub>(R<sub>1</sub>)) × (σ<sub>θ</sub>(R<sub>1</sub>))

as

(ρ<sub>R<sub>2</sub></sub>(σ<sub>θ</sub>(R<sub>1</sub>))) × R<sub>2</sub>

?

The first expression is not efficient since I am doing the same operation twice. So, basically, I am looking for an efficient way to evaluate it.

Comment: And exactly what do you mean with "not efficient"? Do you have an actual implementation that works with relational algebra operations?

Comment: There is an efficiency measure for every relational algebra expression which, for instance, can be number of tuple accesses if we were to implement it.

Comment: So there is no actual implementation. Because implementations (as SQL products have shown) can identify duplicate, identical expressions and not calculate them twice.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. But is the second expression incorrect?

Comment: What is the (1) question?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you use?

R<sub>2</sub> = σ<sub>θ</sub>(R<sub>1</sub>)

and then

R<sub>2</sub> × R<sub>2</sub>

Comment: I can but assignment operator is not a basic relational algebra operator. Every relational algebra expression can be written only using only basic operators (select, project, cartesian product, union, set difference and rename). I just want to know what would be the right expression in this case.

Answer (score -3):

The expression

```
ρR2(σθ(R1)) × R2
```

is not valid because the subscript to the rename operator cannot be a relation.

Comment: No no. The subscript is not a relation. It is the new relation name that I am giving to the expression inside the rename operator.

Comment: So, it is a relation. The expression is not valid.